# How to draw Genogram relationship tree using ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, gojs, family-tree

- I'm looking for a simple Javascript Library (SVG) for the ReactJs module that allows me to
  draw family tree relationships.
- I've already referred GoJs Genogram. But it's paid and does not fully fill our requirements as well.
- What we need to show for relationships in this genogram is shown as the below image

[image]

Comment: If you write down what your requirements are, it will be easier to help you...

Comment: @Ba2sik I'have this much requirement because I have to approach it using dynamic logic with the given relations diagram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To draw a genogram relationship tree using ReactJS, you can utilize various libraries and tools available for creating interactive and customizable diagrams. One popular library for creating diagrams in React is react-d3-tree.